# Drawing an Image on Top on an Image in PictureBox by Capturing MouseUp and MouseMove(Drag and Draw Image)

Tags: c#, .net, image, drawing, gdi+

I'm trying to implement a image editor,i want to draw an image on top of existing  image on a picture box.I have achieved it using Graphics.DrawImage and using the MouseEventArguments point.But the problem is i want a selection rectangle drawn on top of the image being drawn when the mouse is clicked over it and it should be redrawn at a new position obtained by on click  and drag by the mouse(without selection rectangle).The rending of the image at the new position is slow and lots of memory is consumed so i use GC.collect.Please help me to implement the selection.I'm posting what i have done till now below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication32
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap timg, timg2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timg = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            timg2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
           pictureBox1.MouseDown+=new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox1_MouseDown);
         pictureBox1.MouseMove+=new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox1_MouseMove);

        }
        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button ==MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                timg = new Bitmap(timg2);

                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(timg);
                g.DrawImage(pictureBox2.Image, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                pictureBox1.Image = timg;
                g.Dispose();
                GC.Collect();
                //pictureBox1.Invalidate();

            }
        }
        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
                g.DrawImage(pictureBox2.Image, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
               // pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                  g.Dispose();
                  GC.Collect();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: set g public properties, and in form load Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(timg);

Answer (score 4):

You should try moving your drawing code to the OnPaint function and just calling Invalidate from the MouseMove. By recreating a graphics object, painting and disposing on each mouse move event you will kill the CPU / memory. By leaving the graphics creation/disposal to Windows Forms you should get better results. MouseMove events can fire up to 125 times per second whereas OnPaint events fire less frequently. You don't want to be creating three graphics contexts (one per picturebox, one for the Form), two Bitmaps and an invalidate call 125 times per second ...

For instance, a solution instead of the above would be to just have local pre-created bitmaps as member variables in the Form, then on MouseDown record the mouse point and call invalidate. In the OnPaint of your form you could draw both images using g.DrawImage() and the offset plus reticule as you require.

I could give a code example if you were able to explain more thoroughly what you were trying to achieve - can you upload a demo project?

Best regards,

Comment: Burnett Thanks for the answer.Im trying to implement a application that allows the user to move the image on clicking and dragging.I want a selection ribbon/rectangle drawn around the image when user clicks on it.Can you provide me with a code sample please.